install basement toliet
My contractor left a 2' high by 4" pvc sticking out of concrete floor for toilet drain.it looks like it's glued inside another pipe sticking 1/4-1/2" above floor. How do I connect a toilet flange to this? Thank you.

Pictures would be a big help to see what you're dealing with.

Cut the pipe flush with the floor and glue in a toilet flange that fits into a 4 inch pipe.

Alternatively, there's the Oatey Twist-n-Set type that doesn't require glue.
